# Is it possible to test socket.io app with Mocha

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mocha.js

I have a Node.js with Socket.io server. So I want to write tests with Mocha to improve development. I've googled a lot to find anything about testing socket.io server with Mocha and all  I found is http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/01/28/testing-socketio-with-mocha-should-and-socketio-client/

But there are Server and Tests under Mocha's test directory and both starts with Mocha, when I already have working Server and just want to test it.

So i wrote next code:

```
    var assert = require("assert"),
      should = require('should'),
      io = require('socket.io-client'),
      socketURL = 'http://localhost:3102',
      options ={
      transports: ['websocket'],
      'force new connection': true,
      'reconnection delay' : 0,
      'reopen delay' : 0
      };
    describe('Server', function(){
      var socket;
      beforeEach(function(done) {
        // Setup
        console.log('Establishing connection');
        socket = io.connect(socketURL, options);

        socket.on('connect', function() {
          console.log('worked...');
          done();
        });
    });
    ...
      it('should receive messages', function(done){
        socket.on('message', function(data){
          console.log('received');
          done();
        });
    ...
    })
```

And the result is:

```
    Server
    Establishing connection
        1) "before each" hook

      0 passing (2s)
      1 failing

      1) Server "before each" hook:
         Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
          at null. (\npm\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:139:19)
          at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

I've checked server's log and there's no connections.. nothing. It doesn't even tried to connect to server.

So I wonder if it's possible to do the tests with Mocha in this way? When you have complete working server and trying to test request-response functionality.

Comment: I found a solution. The problem was in different versions of socket.io and socket.io-client libs. They must be the same. Now i have socket.io v0.9.16 and socket.io-client v0.9.16 and everything works just fine!